# Handling JSON attribute containing either array or value

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Im receiving JSON objects in my Angular application: I want to fetch some of the values but the problem is that I can't create an TypeScript interface to match those values because for one key the value can either be an array containing multiple values or just a simple value (see "relations").

An example:

```
{
  "ID": "123",
  "name": "dummy",
  "relations": [
      { "rel": "child", "relValue": ["child1", "child2"] },
      { "rel": "parent", "relValue": "parent"}
  ]
}
```

How do I retrieve the values of all elements of this key ("relations"), regardless of whether there is an array or a single value?

Comment: Maybe with a union type? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html

Comment: I didn't notice that the relation also has a slightly different key when there is an array instead of a single value (e.g. 'relValue' vs. 'relValues'). I could achieve handling them differently by using the 'in' keyword to check whether the JSON object had the 'relValue' ot the 'relValues' attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the type you can use

```
type Type = {
    ID: string,
    name: string,
    relations: Array<Record<string, string | string[]>>,
}
```

or more precise

```
type Type = {
    ID: string,
    name: string,
    relations: Array<{ rel: string, relValue: string | string[] }>,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd advise against having a data structure like this if you can, but if you're stuck with it you can have an interface like below using Union types.

```
interface Relations {
    ID: string;
    name: string;
    relations: string | Array<string>
}
```

The reason why I'd advise against this kind of structure is because if you want to use `relations` you'd have to check the type like this:

```
var rel: Relations = ...;
if (rel.relations instanceof Array) {
    //use rel.relations as an array (of string)
}
else {
    //use rel.relations as a string
}
```

without the checks, typescript will get confused because `string` and `Array` does not share the same interface.

Comment: This looks like a good approach but there is a problem. The check whether it is an array or not with instanceof doesn't seem to work, which means that at the moment the values that are in arrays can't be fetched.

Comment: should return `true` if `rel.relations` is an array. Alternatively you can do `typeof rel.relations === "string"` instead of `instanceof`.